# Injecting logger from DI to object created with factory

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I need to add logger (ILogger) to existing object of MyDbConnection, this object is created from Factory which is registered in NET Core DI together with MyOptions class

```
public class MyFactory : IMyFactory
{
    private readonly MyOptions _options;

    public MyFactory(MyOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
    }

    public MyDbConnection CreateDbA() => new MyDbConnection(_options.ConnStrA);
    public MyDbConnection CreateDbB() => new MyDbConnection(_options.ConnStrB);
    public MyDbConnection CreateDbC() => new MyDbConnection(_options.ConnStrC);
}
```

Factory is then injected into service, which then use it to create object and do something

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(IMyFactory factory)
    {
        var a = factory.CreateDbA();
        var b = factory.CreateDbB();
        a.DoSomething();
        b.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

MyDbConnection looks like this:

```
public class MyDbConnection
{
    private string connStr;
    //private ILogger logger;

    //public MyDbConnection(string connStr, ILogger logger)
    public MyDbConnection(string connStr)
    {
        this.connStr = connStr;
        //this.logger = Logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //logger.LogWarning();
    }
}
```

Problem is that I can't just add ILogger and inject it from DI container because factory is using 'new' to create MyDbConnection, without using DI. My only solution currently is to use static logger instead of injected one, but that seems to be a bad solution. Is there another way around this? How it should be done properly?

Comment: You can configure/use DI to get new instances of the `MyDbConnection`.  If that's not something you want, then just add `ILogger` to your factory: `public MyFactory(MyOptions options, ILogger logger)` and pass the injected logger into the new'd up connections.

Comment: A side story: are your connections disposed somehow? Or you just show an example code that just omits disposing?

Comment: @MetroSmurf adding ILogger to factory was also one of my ideas, but after all I decided to try to find a better solution

Comment: @WiktorZychla this is just sample code, based on existing one, I've made it for simplification and to show the problem which I have

Answer (score 0):

The design will need to be refactored to be able to get the desired behavior.

First `MyDbConnection` should be refactored accordingly to depend on the appropriate logger

For example

```
public class MyDbConnection {
    private string connStr;
    private ILogger logger;

    public MyDbConnection(string connStr, ILogger<MyDbConnection> logger) {
        this.connStr = connStr;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        logger.LogWarning();
    }
}
```

Then the factory refactored to use `ActivatorUtilities` to initialize and inject the necessary dependencies via an injected service provider.

```
public class MyFactory : IMyFactory {
    private readonly MyOptions options;
    private readonly IServiceProvider services;

    public MyFactory(MyOptions options, IServiceProvider services) {
        this.options = options;
        this.services = services;
    }

    public MyDbConnection CreateDbA() => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyDbConnection>(services, options.ConnStrA);
    public MyDbConnection CreateDbB() => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyDbConnection>(services, options.ConnStrB);
    public MyDbConnection CreateDbC() => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyDbConnection>(services, options.ConnStrC);
}
```

In the example above the specific dependencies are provided just as before when they were manually initialized. All other dependencies *(like the logger)* will be resolved via the service provider and injected into the target class when it is being initialized.

This way dependency injection can be maintained and manual initialization of `MyDbConnection` can be avoided.

Comment: what about exposing IServiceProvider to factory class? isn't it a bad thing? because then in future someone can use it to for example to resolve items manually?